# How to install Drupal 9 using SQLite on DDEV?

Tags: drupal, ddev

I want to create a new Drupal 9 site from scratch using DDEV and SQLite as database system. How can I do it? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. You can do anything with DDEV :)

As described in the settings.php comments, put this at the end of your settings.php or in a settings.local.php (this will override the settings that DDEV has done for you in settings.ddev.php):

```
$databases['default']['default'] = [
  'driver' => 'sqlite',
  'database' => 'sites/default/files/.ht.sqlite',
];
```

If you don't want the regular database container and PhpMyAdmin container to run, `ddev config --omit-containers=db,dba`

More about settings management in DDEV at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/topics/cms-specific-help/

Comment: Many thanks! Is it planned that SQLite can be configured directly in DDEV's config.yaml as an official database server type?

Comment: No, no plans to incorporate Sqlite into DDEV's configuration; it's not like any production deploy. It's so easy to do without any configuration, as shown here. And, of course, it doesn't add much value. I noted that the install was slower (macOS M1) on sqlite than it would have been on Colima+mutagen.